# No Voltage on IR21844S HIGH OUTPUT (HO) pin

Tags: arduino, mosfet-driver

### I need help, please.
my IR21844S was working when SD (ShutDown active Low) is powered with High logic level  (5V) and Vin with Low logic level  (0V), IR21844S Low Side(LO) = Vcc Voltage and IR21844S High Side(HO) = 0V which "was" Correct. and...
When both SD (ShutDown active Low) and Vin is powered with High Logic level  (5V), IR21844S Low Side(LO) = 0V voltage and IR21844S High Side(HO) = Vcc Voltage which "was" also Correct.

Currently now, when SD (ShutDown active Low) is powered with High logic level  (5V) and Vin with Low logic level  (0V), IR21844S Low Side(LO) = Vcc Voltage and IR21844S High Side(HO) = 0V which is Correct.
But when "both" of the SD (ShutDown active Low) and Vin is powered with High Logic level (5V), IR21844S Low Side(LO) = 0V voltage and IR21844S High Side(HO) = 0.790V - 0.897V according to the Vin PWM signal variation Voltage is not supposed to be.
In a nutshell, IR21844S High Side(HO) is not bringing its voltage anymore when both SD (ShutDown active Low) and Vin is powered with High Logic level  (5V) while IR21844S Low Side(LO) = 0V.

What I noticed I did wrong was that I did not connect the SD(ShutDown active Low) to any Logic Level(High or Low) which I know it shouldn't affect it because it's automatically connected to the GND according to its datasheet Functional Block Diagram but I only connected the Vin to High Logic Level(5V).
secondly, I used a Lead Acid battery 5V 4.5Ah (20hr) as my Logic Level.

logic could be 3.3V or 5V.

The Logic level 5V is meant for the SD(active low) pin so as to Enable the chip to be active and also meant for the Vin(PMW) pin so as to switch the Half-Bridge from its initial position LO = 1 & HO = 0  to  LO = 0 & HO = 1 so that the motor spins clockwise or counterclockwise accordingly to the chip powered.

Now, if the Enable Pin is HIGH (5v) and either PMW1 pin or PMW2 pin is HIGH(with PMW voltage), there should be Movement, right? Yes. which is equivalent to  LO = 0 & HO = 1.
but my own case is different, if the Enable Pin is HIGH (5v) and either PMW1 pin or PMW2 pin is HIGH(with PMW voltage), there will not be Movement. I traced where the problems are then I got to know it was from the Driver High Output(HO) having 0.790V which cannot drive the gate of the transistor and therefore the case is now  LO = 0 & HO = 0.

I hope you'd clearly understand the problems now.

Please Help me out...
Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Add a schematic and lose a lot of the words.